# How do I simply upload a local directory to git

Tags: git, github

UPDATE: I am now informed that github no longer accepts connections using https://github.com/username/repoName, and instead am now using ssh -T git@github.com to connect after following the instructions on setting up SSH with github [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account):

I cannot make head nor tail of github's own instructions on how to upload a repository on my local computer to git.

I have tried

```
 git remote add myDir https://github.com/myGitHubUsername/myAlreadyExistingRepo
```

but I get 'Could not read from remote repository'

I have used the url given in github for the repo (https://github.com/myGitHubUsername/myAlreadyExistingRepo) so I don't understand why it won't work. All the articles I can find on google etc require me to follow this first step, but it doesn't sem to function properly.

I am running the command from inside a directory which I have initialized in git. Could it be a problem with the connection?

Comment: is the folder you're running this command a git repository?

Comment: You can’t just add a remote for a single directory

Comment: Don't use `https` URLs with GitHub.

Comment: @DanielA.White Why can't I add a remote? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @matt Why not? Must I use SSH?

Comment: @FelipeEsteves Yes, and I have made a commit there already.

Comment: @Hektor I think you severely misunderstand how git works. I'd take some time to go through some basic tutorials/explanations so that you know the fundamentals, and then you'll understand GitHub's instructions and why what you are doing won't work.

Comment: Well I know how it works on my local computer, I'm more baffled as to why github's own instructions don't work.

Comment: It would certainly be better to use SSH. GitHub no longer accepts https + username + password.

Comment: @matt So I registered my SSH public key with github, and got the authenticated message. Now back to square 1 - same 'Cannot read remote repo' message. Or am I still making the same mistake using the https://...' url as a parameter? Astonishing that there seems to be no adequate tutes on the subject.

Comment: If you've got SSH configured then don't give an https URL, as I said. That was my original point, remember?

Comment: I have connected simply using ssh -T git@github.com...but what password are they asking for when I try 'git push...'?

Comment: You *can* still use https, but you must use a GitHub-generated authentication string as the password, for private repositories. GitHub call this generated password a "token". It is *functionally* a password except that it has additional controls and can be invalidated without losing your base (log-in-to-GitHub) password. That said, I prefer ssh by far myself.

Comment: You don't use SSH to connect. You tell Git to use it to connect. If you remote add a git@github.com URL there is no password. That's the point.

Comment: For example it is usual to say `git remote add origin git@github.com:mattneub/myCoolRepo.git`. You will need to use some sort of credential manager, but the instructions at GitHub on how to do that are excellent.

Comment: @matt I understand why you say "don't use https URLs with GitHub", but I think it would be better to say "if you use https URLs with GitHub, you must use a Personal Access Token instead of your password". I use https with GitHub all the time without any difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

> So I registered my SSH public key with github, and got the authenticated message

But you still need to switch to SSH for your local repository URL.
(For HTTPS, see your [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73508361/6309))

```bash
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote set-url myDir git@github.com:myGitHubUsername/myAlreadyExistingRepo
git remote -v
git push -u myDir main
```

Note: generally, one would change `origin` instead of `myDir`: `origin` is the default remote *name* used by Git.

Then and only then Git would try and user your `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` default SSH key (or `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa` on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

GitHub works fine with HTTPS, you have been misled.
Please see [Cloning with HTTPS URLs](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls) for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
When Git prompts you for your password, enter your **[personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) (PAT)** instead your password.

> Could not read from remote repository

This error cannot appear after running the `git remote` command. Show us the real output.

> upload a local directory to git

You must be confusing Git and GitHub. If you want to upload the directory to GitHub, this is not possible. Only the repository can be uploaded to GitHub. Commit the directory into the local Git repository and then push it to the remote repository.

So we can help you, show us the output of these commands:

```
  git remote -v
  git branch -vv
  git status
```

Comment: The OP is about pushing to a GitHub repo. Yes you can clone, but to be able to commit changes, you need SSH.

Comment: No, I can do **push** via HTTPS too. Everything works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, a PAT can be used to login for HTTPS push. It seem like the OP was about using SSH

Answer (score -2):

Here is the good pratice, when you try to push an existing repository to github remote existed repo.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/path/to/your/repo.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

I think `origin` is not replaced as `myDir`.

BTW, password authentication is abandond by Github.

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
```

Comment: No, this returns exactly the same error when I run with 'git remote add origin https://github...'

Comment: This does not fix the issue. It needs to be `git@github.com:path/to/your/repo.git` and not HTTPS