# What username and password does ksshaskpass require?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am trying to connect to github using shh:

```
git push -u myDoks main
```

and a popup box from ksshaskpass is asking 'Username for https://github.com'

I have tried entering my email, or my username, and then am asked 'Password for https://myusername@github.com' but after entering my github password I am told the authentification failed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not related to SSH, since Git is asking credentials to an HTTPS URL. For SSH, see your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73507943/6309).

Second, try to enter:

- your Github username account (*not* email: your GitHub login)
- your GitHub *token* (a PAT: [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows), created with [scope `repos`](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps))
  [Since Aug. 2021](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-12-git-password-authentication-is-shutting-down/), GitHub  no longer accepts account passwords when authenticating Git operations on GitHub.com.

Finally, make sure you have set a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) to cache said credentials.

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

On Windows, GCM is already installed ([Git Credential Manager from Microsoft](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager), cross-platform: you can [install it](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager#download-and-install) on Mac or Linux).

```
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
```

You can then register your token (cache it in the underlying credential vault used by GCM), even on Windows, even in a simple CMD (you don't even need a `git bash` session):

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=YourAccount\npassword=YourToken" | git credential-manager-core store
```

That way, Git won't ask you again for your credentials on the next `git push`.

Make sure:

- `<path/to/Git>/mingw64/bin` is in your `%PATH%`/`$PATH`: that is where `git-credential-manager-core` will reside (for recent Git versions anyway 2.35+).
- `<path/to/Git>/bin/bin` is in your `%PATH%`/`$PATH`: that is where `printf` will reside (needed for Windows OS which does not have a built-in shell `printf` command in its shell).